# Responsive Smooth Scroll CSS3 Animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I've been trying to get a smooth scroll animation for a while now, but mainly in JS.. 
This hasn't been working out that well so I decided to try in CSS3. 
Now I want to make this animation responsive by calling a JS function which adds the CSS rules for the animation responsive to the object the animation is for. Here is the JS code I've got so far. I'll also leave a Fiddle, but I'm new to that so things might not work right away.

```
function getTexts() {

    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('toplink');

    for (x = 0, len = element.length;  x < len; x++){

        var ID = element[x].textContent.toLowerCase();
        var object = document.getElementById(ID);
        console.log(object);
        addCSSAnimator(ID);

    }
}

function addCSSAnimator(el) {

    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    var DOM = document.getElementById(el);
    var Class = DOM.getAttribute("class");
    var Parent = DOM.parentElement.getAttribute("id");
    var rect = DOM.getBoundingClientRect();

    var rule = ".toplink[ id= '"+el+"' ]:target - #"+Parent+" div."+Class+" {\n" +
        "-webkit-transform: translateY( +"+rect.y.toPrecision(4)+'px'+" );\n" +
        "transform: translateY( +"+rect.y.toPrecision(4)+'px'+" );\n" +
        "}";

    console.log("Stylesheet: ",sheet," object: ",DOM," Class: ",Class," offset X&Y:",rect.x," ",rect.y);

    console.log(rule);

    sheet.insertRule("body { background-color: 0; }", 1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dtj46c64/

Answer (score 0):

You may try moving to jquery for this solution. Use document.ready and window.resize functions to handle the animation and also instead of for loop. use the jquery .each() function to get the elements. Try working around the following code i changed for you to go along with. Hope this puts you in the right direction to achieve your goal:

```
 <script>
    function getTexts() {

        $(".toplink").each(function () {
            let ID = $(this)
            console.log(ID);
            addCSSAnimator(ID);
        });
    }

    function addCSSAnimator(el) {

        var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
        var DOM = el;
        var Class = DOM.attr("class");
        var Parent = DOM.parent().attr("id");
        var rect = DOM[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        var rule = ".toplink[ id= '" + el + "' ]:target - #" + Parent + " div." + Class + " {\n" +
            "-webkit-transform: translateY( +" + rect.top.toPrecision(4) + 'px' + " );\n" +
            "transform: translateY( +" + rect.top.toPrecision(4) + 'px' + " );\n" +
            "}";

        console.log("Stylesheet: ", sheet, " object: ", DOM, " Class: ", Class, " offset X&Y:", rect.left, " ", rect.top);

        console.log(rule);

        sheet.insertRule("body { background-color: 0; }", 1);

    }

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        getTexts();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        getTexts();
    });
    </script>
```

Notice i changed the rect.y to rect.top as on some browsers the getBoundingClientRect fucntion does not return x and y values but left and top are always filled.

Also dont know why you are getting id of the parent of the object as there is no id set to the parent of the anchor class="toplink" so it will always return as null or empty.

Sorry for not a 100% answer as got busy but i hope the solution so far i suggested will help you tweak and find what your looking for.